# Finch Light Sensors as Pretest condition for Obstacle Avoidance

Tags: java, light-sensor

I am trying to create a basic obstacle avoidance behavior, but I want it to only function if the light sensors are over a certain value.

```
while (!myFinch.isBeakDown())
{
    myFinch.getLeftLightSensor();
    light = myFinch.getLeftLightSensor();   

    if (light >= 20)
    {
        if (myFinch.isObstacleLeftSide())
        {
            myFinch.setWheelVelocities(-255,-255,750);
            myFinch.setWheelVelocities(100,-255, 500);
        }   
        else if (myFinch.isObstacleRightSide())
        {
            myFinch.setWheelVelocities(-255,-255,750);
            myFinch.setWheelVelocities(-255, 100, 500);
        }  
        else
        {
            myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,255);
        }    
    }
}
```

*EDIT*  Working Obstacle Avoidance code without light pretest.  Obstacle avoidance works without the light pretest and I also tested the IR sensors in the netbeans sensor test.

```
 // Run so long as the Finch is not pointed beak down
  while(!myFinch.isBeakDown()) 
{


    if(myFinch.isObstacleLeftSide()) 
    {

        myFinch.setWheelVelocities(-255,-255,750);
        myFinch.setWheelVelocities(100,-255, 500);

    }
    // If there's an obstacle on the right, set LED blue, back up for 750 ms
    // and turn for 500 ms
    else if(myFinch.isObstacleRightSide()) 
    {

        myFinch.setWheelVelocities(-255,-255,750);
        myFinch.setWheelVelocities(-255, 100, 500);


    }
    // Else, robot goes straight
    else
    {
        myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,255);

    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `light` is never updated, use

```
while (!myFinch.isBeakDown())
{
    light = myFinch.getLeftLightSensor();
    myFinch.sleep(1);

    if (light >= 20)
    {
        if (myFinch.isObstacleLeftSide())
        {
            myFinch.setWheelVelocities(-255,-255,750);
            myFinch.setWheelVelocities(100,-255, 500);
        }   
        else if (myFinch.isObstacleRightSide())
        {
            myFinch.setWheelVelocities(-255,-255,750);
            myFinch.setWheelVelocities(-255, 100, 500);
        }  
        else
        {
            myFinch.setWheelVelocities(255,255);
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I corrected it and I can now use light as a pretest condition for general movement, but I still can't get obstacle avoidance to work.  It completely ignores the IR sensors for some reason.

Comment: Are you able to get `isObstacleLeftSide()` or `isObstacleRightSide()` to return true by putting a hand in front of the sensors?

Comment: No, not while using light as the pretest condition.  I've used the sensor test in netbeans and they work fine.  They also work if the application contains only an obstacle avoidance behavior.  As soon as light is introduced, they don't return anything.

Comment: Not sure, maybe remove `myFinch.getLeftLightSensor();` and add a `myFinch.sleep(1);` after `light = myFinch.getLeftLightSensor();`?

Comment: It didn't work.  Thanks for the help anyway.  I'll keep working on it.